# Batch file open->closes nothing happens

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-8.1

I wrote this bat file to run a program i wrote in python

```
@echo off
python C:\Project\myProg\main.py
pause
```

but nothing happens, when i click it twice just open closes nothing runs.
If I open a cmd and type just `python C:\Project\myProg\main.py` it works and runs.
I tried to `Run as Administrator`, but I get the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: does your company has security policies to prevent `.bat` files to be run from folders other than the ones specified? You could try to run your script from a CMD prompt to see what the message is. I just made a test on my company PC and I get the same exact problem. But running from a CMD I get an explicit message (in french, sorry: `Ce programme est bloqué par une stratégie de groupe. Pour plus d'informations, contactez votre administrateur système`.).

Comment: I changed the file to have just `@echo off
python main.py
pause` and put the file in the right folder, still the same

Comment: try running _your .bat file_ from a CMD window so you'll see the error.

Comment: I just get whatever is written on the file all in one line. `offpython C:\Project\myProg\main.pypause`

Comment: @Mumfordwiz Save your batch file as __ANSI__ file. You have saved your batch file most likely as UTF-16 encoded Unicode file.

Comment: it worked. Thank You!

Comment: Also another way to start a python program in Windows would be to create a shortcut and put same instruction (i.e. python C:\Project\myProg\main.py) as Target. You would even be able to set an icon for your program.